# ¿Como utilizo cut en un for de un archivo linea a linea?

Tags: bash, archivo, bucle-for, shell, cut

La idea es la siguiente:
Paso por parámetro un archivo que en cada linea tiene un 2 archivos separados por guion, por ejemplo

```
cat pruebas.txt
hola.txt-adios.txt
buenas.txt-quetal.txt
```

lo que tengo que hacer es comprobar por cada linea si el primer archivo existe (el primero antes del guion) y si existe copiar su contenido en el segundo (después del guion) eso por cada linea
Mi código es el siguiente

```
#!/bin/bash

#Comprobacion de parametros
if `test $# -ne 1`
then
    echo "Numero de parametros incorrectos" 
    echo "Uso del programa: $0 archivo"
    exit 1;
fi

for parejas in $1
do
    primerArchivo=`cat $parejas | cut -d"-" -f1`
    segundoArchivo=`cat $parejas | cut -d"-" -f2`

    if test -e $primerArchivo 
    then
        `cat $primerArchivo > $segundoArchivo`
    else
        `cat /etc/group > $segundoArchivo`
    fi
done
```

El problema creo que esta en que el al hacer el cut me coge todas el primer campo pero de todas las lineas y entonces no me funciona bien.

Answer (score 1):

En tu código veo algo diferente a lo que preguntas. Ya que, en caso de que no existiera el primer archivo, copias el contenido de `/etc/group`. Sin embargo, te puedes guiar con este script. Puedes quitar los comentarios para ver el contenido del archivo y las secciones que genera.

```
#!/bin/bash

lista_archivos="$1"

while read archivos || [[ -n "$archivos" ]]
do
    #echo "archivos: $archivos"
    while IFS='-' read archivo_obj archivo_dest 
    do
        #echo "archivo_obj:$archivo_obj"
        #echo "archivo_dest:$archivo_dest"

        if [[ ! -e "$archivo_obj" ]]
        then
            #Aqui puedes hacer el cp /etc/group "$archivo_dest"
            echo "\"$archivo_obj\" no existe."              
        elif [[ ! -s "$archivo_obj" ]]
        then
            echo "\"$archivo_obj\" esta vacio."
        else
            cp "$archivo_obj" "$archivo_dest"
        fi
    done <<< "$archivos"

done < "$lista_archivos"
```

Puedes prescindir de `cut`, lo cual es ligeramente mejor porque así ya no desperdicias recursos utilizando otro programa y mejor utilizas los *builtins* de `bash`.